# equivalent of the cwt (matlab) function for octave gui?

Tags: matlab, octave, wavelet-transform

I'd like to use a [Continuous wavelet transform (CWT)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_wavelet_transform) function in my octavegui code.

in Octave gui CWT is not available - is there equivalent .pkg to use a cwt?

[fwt](https://octave.sourceforge.io/ltfat/overview.html) is available in the [ltfat.pkg](https://octave.sourceforge.io/ltfat/overview.html)- but this seems to be something different than cwt.

According to the [pdf](http://wiki.octave.org/wiki/images/0/0c/Slides_octconf_zdenel_prusa.pdf) from Prusa a form of a CWT is a Morlet or a mexican hat ("Continuous Wavelet Transfom – CWT (Morlet, Mexican hat, . . . ).= - is it possible to use a Morlet function in Octave? or is this something different?

any suggestions? (I am not a mathematician)

thank You

Answer (score 0):

If none of [these functions](https://octave.sourceforge.io/list_functions.php?q=wavelet&sort=package) cover your needs, then you have two other options:

- Use a c++ or java package within octave. Octave has [external interfaces](https://octave.org/doc/interpreter/External-Code-Interface.html#External-Code-Interface) for both.
- Use a simple python / julia / whatever scripts to perform specific calculations using your favourite wavelet package natively in that language, and use .mat converters to pass data (e.g. [scipy.io.loadmat  / savemat](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/io.html#matlab-files) in python, and [MAT.jl](https://github.com/JuliaIO/MAT.jl) for julia) in and out of octave. Octave provides a 'python' function for executing python scripts for convenience (but this is no more than a nicely wrapped system call).

In any case, unfortunately that does mean you would need to know a bit of python / c++ / java respectively.

You can find a nice list of wavelet packages [here](http://www.wavelets.org/software.php).

Another thing you could try, is scilab. It is similar to octave (though not identical), and provides a [wavelet package](https://atoms.scilab.org/toolboxes/swt). There's also a module which allows [intercommunication between octave and scilab](https://wiki.octave.org/Sci_cosim).

Do have a look at the octave forge list first though. It's been a while, but last time I worked with wavelets I remember those covered my needs more than adequately.

---

PS. I did not mention [Wavelab](http://statweb.stanford.edu/~wavelab/) above, because their website does not mention this, and I don't know if it actually works on octave. Also, it seems a bit outdated. But in theory there's no reason why it wouldn't work, might as well give their .mex files a try if it seems relevant to you.

---

PS2. If something works for you, feel free to leave a comment here for future readers.

Comment: PS3: This is also a good read: https://uk.mathworks.com/help/wavelet/gs/continuous-and-discrete-wavelet-transforms.html